# Swift Method reflection at runtime

Tags: ios, macos, reflection, swift, introspection

i need to discover a bunch of classes and methods (including the parameters and return values) in a particularly directory without knowing any name (of class) in advance (except for the directory).

This reflection has to be done at runtime, but if it's not possible, i'll do it in build time.

I found some basic reflection in Swift for the attributes of a knowing class, but there isn't information about the methods and you have to know the class in advance:

```
/// Sample class
class Class {
    var attribute1:String="value1"
    var attribute2:String="value2"
    func method(){
        println("method")
    }
    func method(param:String) -> Bool{
        println("method with params")
        return true
    }
}

/// Attribute reflection
var reflectClass = reflect(Class())

for var i=0; i<reflectClass.count; i++ {
    println("attr name: \(reflect(Class())[i].0)")
    println("attr value: \(reflect(Class())[i].1.summary)")
}
```

Is that possible in Swift?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you found any workaround solving the problem of discovering instance methods in pure swift classes?

Answer (score 0):

Because the Swift compiler is written in C++ and is open source athttps://github.com/apple/swift it would be possible for you to modify the Swift compiler to invoke functionality inhttps://github.com/apple/swift/tree/main/stdlib/public/runtime to traverse any & all detail in a Swift-runtime framework from Apple to textually dump out whichever information you seek in human-readable form.